# (CentOS) default FTP (SFTP) Log File?

Tags: centos, logs, ftp, sftp, audit

I'm on `CentOS v6.4` and using its native FTP Server, which i suppose is `sftp`. *(Am i right?)* Now i can use FTP well. But i need to log the actions taken by Users.

Logs for the actions, such us, who logged in, who modified which files, who deleted which files .. etc the basically important actions, you know.

So my simple questions would be:

- Where & how can i access/check the FTP Logs from Server, please?
- Can it even be done with default `SFTP`? *(Do i need `vsftpd`?)*

In short words, what is the best & simplest way to get the FTP Logging, please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can log `sftp`, try this:

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, change this line:

```
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

to:

```
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -l INFO -f AUTH
```

Then config `syslog` log facility `AUTH` to your file. In Centos 6. edit `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, add this line:

```
auth.*    /var/log/sftp.log
```

After making these changes reload (`kill -HUP`) or restart `sshd` and restart `rsyslog` for them to take effect.

Comment: Updated answer!

Comment: Oh ok, then after that, what should i do please? RESTART some services?

Comment: Yes, restart `sshd` and `rsyslog` services to make the changes.

Comment: Thanks so much, for the updates as well. I have ACCEPTED it already! (Since seems you have a good experience in this) Can i please add some comments to ask that, in this LOGS, (1) why can't i see the user's name, instead of just logging the activities only? (2) is there a log size or retention limit on this log-file please? (up to how long can i keep the logs in this file?) Thanks much again!!

Comment: `-l DEBUG` still can't help, to describe WHICH USER. And what you mean by `logrotate` please? :)

Comment: Hi do u mean to change to, `auth.* /var/log/sftp.log` in rsyslog?

Comment: Hi Gnouc, no need to restart `rsyslog` anymore? (according to your answer)

Comment: I have updated it.

Comment: Please kindly accept my latest edit request (changing to AUTH)

Comment: @夏期劇場 Is it a convention to name it AUTH?

Answer (score 3):

Mmmmm..but now there are another problem. `/var/log/sftp.log` grows without control...
Add entry to `/etc/logrotate.d/sftp`

```
/var/log/sftp.log
{
    rotate 24
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

Comment: /etc/logrotate.d/sftp instead of /etc/logrote.d/sftp